# how to import .CSV file into Drools

Tags: java, csv, import, drools, rule-engine

I am new to using Drools Rule Engine and have downloaded the 6.2.0.Final zip and all the other files to allow the Rule engine to work. However, my first issue is that where are the examples kept in order to see how the Rules engine actually functions, and secondly how would i be able to import a CSV file into Eclipse which can then be read, and then generate a new CSV file as an output? or if there are examples available, where could i find them? i have looked everywhere and have had no luck,

thanks

Comment: A CSV file has nothing to do with Drools, so your second issue isn't a Drools issue. If you have a CSV file, Excel or some other program may provide you with a conversion tool.  And your first issue: the Drools distribution comes with a set of examples for using Drools; as for the way the Rule engine works: you have the source code. Some hints can be found in the Drools documentation, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSV file but you can use XLS file this will work fine.

**For Adding decision table -** 
After creating drools project in Eclipse just 
`right click on src/main/resources/rules -> New -> other -> DecisionTable -> Next -> provide a name -> Finish.`

This will create a new Decision table with example in it.

If you are facing issues while creating Drools project in Eclipse then follow - [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.1/html/Development_Guide/) section 6.1.3.

If you are facing issues in configuring drools rule engine with eclipse then follow - [link](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch03.html).

To configure Drools runtime follow - [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/drools/drools_eclipse_plugin.htm)

Comment: What if I don't want to use xls? My IDE dont do textual reserach on it.